# Contradicting statements about CRC burst error detection performance

Tags: crc

Wikipedia states:

> Typically an n-bit CRC applied to a data block of arbitrary length
> will detect any single error burst not longer than n bits, and the
> fraction of all longer error bursts that it will detect is (1−2^−n).

This means there are two probabilities for burst error detection performance: One up to the width of the CRC (100%) and one above that width (<100%)

However I have seen other sources like German Wikipedia that say there are three different probabilities. For CRC-16 it states (translated from German):

> Furthermore, all burst errors with a length of 16 or less are reliably
> detected. Burst errors with a length of 17 are detectable with a
> probability of 0.99997. All burst errors with a length of 18 and more
> are detectable with a probability of 0.99998.

So which is right? Are there two or three different probabilities? How are they calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an *n*-bit CRC and a *k*-bit burst error, the probability of a false positive is *(2<sup>max(k – n, 0)</sup> – 1) / (2<sup>k</sup> – 1)*. One minus that is the probability of a *k*-bit burst error detection. So:

```
15  1
16  1
17  0.999992
18  0.999989
19  0.999987
20  0.999986
21  0.999985
22  0.999985
```

In the limit, you get *1 – 2<sup>-n</sup>*.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you again. Seems both Wikipedia sections are a shame. The German numbers are simply wrong and the English section withholds a big simplification. Anyway, is this common knowledge for you or could you link to a webpage or literature where that accurate information can be found?

Comment: BTW https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/153610/57311

Comment: I don't have a reference handy. I'm sure this is shown early in any elementary discussion of CRCs.